# Sketch SVG Linear Gradient is black instead of white in the browser

Tags: css, svg, linear-gradients

I have a simple SVG that I have drawn is Sketch 2.

The shape is a simple skewed rectangle, that has a linear gradient, from top to bottom. White at the top, with 75% opacity, and white at the bottom too, with 0% opacity.

[image]

I have added a grey background in the example above, so you can see the shape and liner gradient.

My problem is, when I export the SVG, and use it as a `background-image` in CSS, the white changes to black.

Here is the SVG that is exported from Sketch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="150px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 150 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <description>Created with Sketch (http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch)</description>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1" stop-color="#FFFFFF">
            <stop stop-opacity="0.75" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <path d="M100.099413,0 L0,0 L49.9005867,50 L150,50 L100.099413,0 Z" id="Rectangle-1" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And here is the minified SVG:

```
<svg width="150" height="50" viewBox="0 0 150 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Untitled</title><defs><linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="a" stop-color="#fff"><stop stop-opacity=".75" offset="0%"/><stop stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"/></linearGradient></defs><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M100.1 0H0l49.9 50H150L100.1 0z" fill="url(#a)"/></g></svg>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this would appear like this; the SVG looks correct to me. Why would the SVG render as a negative in the browser?

Just for clarification, when I reopen either the exported or minified SVG in Sketch again, it is rendered correctly (a white liner gradient).

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks just the same to me as a background-image or not. Perhaps it's a UA bug. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Thanks Robert, but yes, I have tried various browsers (Chrome, FF, IE9+, Safari, etc.).

Comment: OK, given that whenI do it it works there must be issues in something you haven't shown us. What exactly is the syntax of your background-image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `stop-color` to the [`stop`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#StopElement) elements:

```css
body {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="50" viewBox="0 0 150 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
      <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="0.75" offset="0%"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <path d="M100.099413,0 L0,0 L49.9005867,50 L150,50 L100.099413,0 Z" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```